# CSS height and border right issues

Tags: html, css, height, border

How can I get `border-right` on my first `.section` div to be the same height as the other section divs, so that when a user inputs more content, they both stay the same height.

To help illustrate this, I've created a picture and [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcLyp/) to help you understand what I mean.

[image]

I've tried messing around with static `heights`, and `min-height` with no success as to what I want to accomplish.

Is there any better way of doing this besides the way I am currently doing it within jsfiddle? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sections.. rather than `display: inline-block;` use `display: table-cell;`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/tcLyp/1/)

- May not function properly with older version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ha, the one thing I forgot to try.  Appreciate it!